# How to load locations on google map(lat & long) from json within 5 miles from current location

Tags: android, json, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a fragment with loads all the shops locations on the google maps. But now I want to load only the shops within 5 miles from current location.

This is my code:

```
public class NearMeFragment extends Fragment implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

        GoogleMap map;
        LatLng latlng;
        private LocationRequest lr;
        private LocationClient lc;
        MapFragment mapFragment;
        //ImageView iv;
        private static View view;
        Response response;

    public NearMeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(view);
        }


        File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/json.txt");
            if(file.exists()) {
                try{
                       Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));

                       Gson gson = new Gson();
                       this.response = gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader, Response.class);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (@SuppressWarnings("hiding") IOException e){
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Error");
            }

        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_near_me, container,
                    false);

            mapFragment = ((MapFragment) this.getActivity()
                    .getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));

            map = mapFragment.getMap();
            map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

            for(Shop shop : this.response.shops){
                for(int i = 0; i < shop.getShopLat().size(); i++){

                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(shop.getShopLat().get(i)), Double.parseDouble(shop.getShopLng().get(i)))).title(shop.getName()));
                }
            }
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Google Play Services missing !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (InflateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Problems inflating the view !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Google Play Services missing !",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return view;
        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lr = LocationRequest.create();
        lr.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        lc = new LocationClient(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), this, this);
        lc.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location l2) {
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(l2.getLatitude(), l2.getLongitude()), 15);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        lc.requestLocationUpdates(lr, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {

    }
}
```

This code works well but takes time to load. I think my issue can be solved by using some if statements. But couldn't figure it out how. Can someone help me to solve it? Also when ever I launch this activity/fragment, I see some other country in Africa. How do I change to UK as default?

Answer (score 0):

this may help you:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-displaying-places-of-interest/

Start from page 3 of the tutorial. Also, looking at the query string that that guy has implemented:

```
String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
                "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
                "&radius=1000&sensor=true" +
                "&key=AIzaSyAXxxoI2aDYyXTUdu3eOTXayrOcWB6F-_I";//ADD KEY
```

Change radius to suit your needs. Note the radius value is in METRES. So your value for 5 miles would be something like 8046.72 (according to google, not sure if the decimal place will work).

I hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the distanceTo() or distanceBetween() method of the Location class to find the distance between each shop and the current location.  Use that in an if statement within you for Shop loop.